# unable to join two or more class in parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have used this code ... i have two class named as **addcomment** and **addpost** and a key **facebookId** available in both. Now i want to get data from both table where **facebookId** is matched

Thanks in advance.....

```
 PFQuery *innerQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"addcomment"];
    [innerQuery whereKeyExists:@"facebookId"];
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"addpost"];
    [query whereKey:@"facebookId" matchesQuery:innerQuery];
    [query includeKey:@"addcomment"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *comments, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"comments array data is  :%@",comments);
        // comments now contains the comments for posts with images
    }];
```

Comment: Do you have a relationship between `addcomment` and `addpost`?

Comment: how can i make relation between these two...

Comment: https://www.parse.com/docs/relations_guide see this link for making relation between two class in parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get objects from two tables unless one has a relation (or pointer) to the other. If all they have in common is the facebookId, then you will only get objects from *addcomment* or *addpost*.

It seems to me that comments would belong to a post(?). If you include a pointer between them, you can get objects from both classes using `includeKey`.